# Add direct link to comment in the moderator flag queue

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, flags, moderator-tools

Whenever a comment is flagged, there are a couple of links in the ♦ moderator flag queue:

[image]

1. is a link to the flag queue (i.e. the page you're already on); it points to this specific comment/flag. The only time I can imagine that this is useful is when you want to share this specific comment/flag in the ♦ moderator chatroom.
2. the author of the comment
3. the flagger (my sock in this case)

The comment itself is also clickable, but that's just for editing the comment inline.

If we want to see the comment in context, we have to click the link to the *post* and from there scroll to the comment itself. If there are a lot of comments or the post is very long, this takes unnecessarily much time.

It makes more sense to me if link 1. would be a direct link to the comment, and the flag timestamp ('8 secs ago') link to the flag queue itself (the current function of link 1.) Note that the timestamp of the comment on the Q&A pages also creates a direct link to the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the [new Moderator Dashboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328838/295232), this is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed); the comment is shown with a clickable timestamp, just like on the normal Q&A page.

[image]